# How do I implement smooth camera moving like lerping with Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, camera

I want to implement some smooth camera movement with Three.js. What I have now (redacted, but shown below) works properly, I can click hold and drag and move around my scene and my camera moves. But I want the camera to move smoothly like with acceleration and deacceleration, like this website: https://annoyingmuseum.zendesk.com/. Right now, as soon as I let go of my click and drag mousedown even, the camera just stops. The effect I am trying to achieve is similar to Three.js's OrbitalControls dampening effect.

```
import * as THREE from "three";

export default class Experience {
    constructor(options = {}) {
        this.camera = new Camera();
        this.renderer = new Renderer(this.canvas);
        this.drag = new THREE.Vector2();


        this.animate();
        this.onMouseDrag();
    }

    updateCamera(event) {
        if (event.movementX > 0) {
            this.drag.x -= event.movementX * 0.01;
        } else {
            this.drag.x -= event.movementX * 0.01;
        }
        if (event.movementY > 0) {
            this.drag.y -= event.movementY * 0.01;
        } else {
            this.drag.y -= event.movementY * 0.01;
        }
        this.camera.position.x = this.drag.x;
        this.camera.position.z = this.drag.y;
    }

    onMouseDrag() {
        let holder = this.updateCamera.bind(this);

        window.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
            window.addEventListener("mousemove", holder);
        });
        window.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
            window.removeEventListener("mousemove", holder);
        });
    }


    animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    }
}
```

This is what I tried so far, but it doesn't do any smoothing and just makes my camera jump and glitch around whenever I click and drag to move around. But after I release my mouth there is smooth movement. The only problem is that it's jumping around.

```
constructor(options = {}) {
    this.cameraTargetPosition = new THREE.Vector3(0, 20, 12); //added starting position
    // ...
}
updateCamera(event) {
    if (event.movementX > 0) {
        this.cameraTargetPosition.x -= event.movementX * 0.01; //changed these from "this.drag"
    } else {
        this.cameraTargetPosition.x -= event.movementX * 0.01;
    }
    if (event.movementY > 0) {
        this.cameraTargetPosition.y -= event.movementY * 0.01;
    } else {
        this.cameraTargetPosition.y -= event.movementY * 0.01;
    }
}

animate() {
    this.camera.position.lerp(this.cameraTargetPosition, 0.4); //added this
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, the solution I posted works, I had some extra code that was glitching my system out. This has the dampening "lerping" effect that I was aiming for.

```
constructor(options = {}) {
    this.cameraTargetPosition = new THREE.Vector3(0, 20, 12); //added starting position
    // ...
}
updateCamera(event) {
    if (event.movementX > 0) {
        this.cameraTargetPosition.x -= event.movementX * 0.01; //changed these from "this.drag"
    } else {
        this.cameraTargetPosition.x -= event.movementX * 0.01;
    }
    if (event.movementY > 0) {
        this.cameraTargetPosition.y -= event.movementY * 0.01;
    } else {
        this.cameraTargetPosition.y -= event.movementY * 0.01;
    }
}

animate() {
    this.camera.position.lerp(this.cameraTargetPosition, 0.4); //added this
    //...
}
```